# SQL - exists, join or in?

Tags: sql, join, exists

I have 3 tables. "TERM", "PERFORMANCE" and "COMPANY". The TERM table has references to PERFORMANCE.ID and PERFORMANCE has foreign key to COMPANY.ID. How I can get only performances, which has:

```
terms >= now and not null
and only from specific company

╔════════════╦════╦═════════════╦════╦═════════╗
║ TERM       ║    ║ PERFORMANCE ║    ║ COMPANY ║
║ ========== ║ -> ║ =========== ║ -> ║ ======= ║
║ start_date ║    ║ price       ║    ║ name    ║
║ ...        ║    ║ ...         ║    ║ ...     ║
╚════════════╩════╩═════════════╩════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp  
 http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Start with those, rest you will figure out after some reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Perfomance a 
INNER JOIN Term b on a.XX = b.XX
INNER JOIN Company c on a.XX = c.XX
where
C.Name = ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T.start_date, P.price, C.name  
FROM PERFORMANCE P JOIN
     COMPANY C ON P.COMPANY.ID=C.ID JOIN
     TERM T ON T.PERFORMANCE.ID=P.ID
```

Try to learn more about `JOIN`s.